How to connect an Electron app to a TSC TE200 printer for printing QR codes and text?
I'm working on an Electron app (for Windows) where users input five values. From the first value, a QR code is generated, and I need the app to send this QR code along with the other four values to a TSC TE200 printer for printing. Currently, the Electron app successfully generates the QR code and displays it.
However, I'm unsure about the best approach to connect the Electron app to the TSC TE200 printer for printing. Could anyone provide tips or ideas on how to achieve this?

Establishing a connection between the Electron app and the TSC TE200 printer.
Sending both the QR code and the other four values to the printer for printing.
Any necessary configurations or libraries required for interfacing with the TSC TE200 printer.

I've tried looking on the internet but from what I've found I'm not sure what would be the best way to do it.
